# Why does the IPCC 1.5 degrees report say "Do not quote, cite or distribute" at the bottom of every page?

Tags: publications, citations

I thought I'd have a look at the recent IPCC special report on global warming of 1.5 degrees. From wikipedia, the link to the report was given as:
https://www.ipcc.ch/report/sr15/

At that site, there are links to the chapters of the report, and every chapter I've looked at so far has "Do Not Cite, Quote or Distribute" at the bottom of every page.

Who is that an instruction to. Me? Why wouldn't the IPCC want people quoting or citing their report?

- Is the link on wikipedia to the wrong version?
- Have the IPCC published the wrong version?

  - (Implying here that people granted access to a draft version shouldn't be sharing it)

I've never seen a footer like this before, but I see something similar is recommended here in [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/51931/whats-the-standard-text-that-i-should-put-at-the-bottom-of-a-handout-containing)

Comment: It's probably because this version is not yet copy edited.

Comment: @StefanS But it's already been released?

Comment: The link you have it's correct. I will email one of the authors to ask about this.

Comment: I think it's still going through some copyediting, you can see in the page that it says " Subject to correction, copy-editing, layout and "trickleback" adjustments to the text of the full report to ensure consistency with the approved Summary for Policymakers "

Comment: @HermanToothrot Interesting that the un-copy-edited version is available on the website, and that it wasn't finalised before being released. Maybe I'll wait before reading. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I've seen this quote during IPCC expert reviews on circulated documents. I believe all their drafts have this disclaimer.

Comment: Perhaps they don’t want to be quoted, as some people who quote stuff use selective editing so the “quote” shows what they want...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just got this reply from one of the lead authors:
"*The 1.5°C Special Report indeed still had a "do not cite/do not quote" label on it, but that is in the meantime removed. Important to note, however, is that the version of the report that is currently online will still be subject to copy-edits as well as consistency edits, which can be significant. By the time of the UNFCCC climate summit in Katowice in December of this year, this should all be updated.*"